# navbar bootstrap не корректно работает на компьютере

Tags: javascript, bootstrap4, navigationbar

Выгрузил проект на хостинг, заметил одну проблему.
Навигационная панель не корректно работает, вот 2 ситуации:

1. С компьютера: ссылки есть, структура корректная, но переход по ссылкам не происходит.
2. Проблема решается, если отключить main.min.js
3. Однако, если выполнить п.2, в мобильной версии сайта навигационная панель не раскрывается.

Собственно, вопрос, как это вылечить и почему это происходит?)
Спасибо!

[ссылка на сайт](http://ajax.itimmy.ru)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот конкретно за блокировку работы навигации, полагаю, отвечает вот этот кусок в самом конце:

```
    $.easing.def = "easeInOutQuad",
    $("li.nav-item").click(function(e) {
        var t = $(this).parent().next();
        $(".catalog-dropdown").not(t).slideUp("slow"),
        t.slideToggle("slow"),
        e.preventDefault()
    })
```

В частности можно, например закомментировать

```
e.preventDefault()
```

Ну или, если уж готовы отключить main.min.js и остальное особо не нужно, то для мобильной версии обойтись парой строчек попроще:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".navbar-toggler").click(function() {
    $("#navbarNavDropdown").slideToggle();
  });

});
```

```css
#navbarNavDropdown {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Переключить навигацию">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">Open</span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="http://ajax.itimmy.ru/" title="Главная" class="nav-link">
          <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
            <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Главная</font>
          </font>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="index.php?id=2" title="О компании" class="nav-link">
          <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
            <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">О компании</font>
          </font>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="index.php?id=3" title="Каталог" class="nav-link">
          <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
            <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Каталог</font>
          </font>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="index.php?id=4" title="Объекты" class="nav-link">
          <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
            <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Объекты</font>
          </font>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="index.php?id=5" title="Новости" class="nav-link">
          <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
            <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Новости</font>
          </font>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="index.php?id=6" title="Чёрный список" class="nav-link">
          <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
            <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Чёрный список</font>
          </font>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="index.php?id=7" title="Контакты" class="nav-link">
          <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
            <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Контакты</font>
          </font>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Спасибо!
Действительно, я баловался с вертикальным меню и пытался сделать dropdown. Отказавшись в дальнейшем, забыл почистить ненужный скрипт)

А не подскажете, как вы идентифицировали проблему? Ведь конфликтов в console браузера нету...)

Comment: а это не то чтобы проблема, чтобы в консоли что-то отображалось. Всего лишь предположила, что висит событие на подпунктах меню и что-то типа запрета на дальнейшее срабатывание ссылок.